# where are default acpi hotkey actions configured?

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, thinkpad

Previously, I used Xubuntu 18.04 and later 20.04 on a ThinkPad X1 Carbon 5th Gen.
As I recall, there was no default binding for the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> hotkey to mute/unmute the mic. I wrote my own script and bound it as an application shortcut using `xfce4-keyboard-settings`.

I now have a ThinkPad X1 6th Gen with a fresh install of Xubuntu 22.04. The <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> hotkey works out of the box and a nice notification pops up with microphone icon showing mute or active.

However, I noticed recently that the microphone is no longer being muted: although the notification still pops up and the icon toggles each time, the F4 led never lights and `pavucontrol` shows input is always being captured (the meter moves when there is sound).

My custom script basically just did `amixer set Capture toggle`. This still works: when I do that, the F4 led toggles and `pavucontrol` meter shows (lack of) response to sounds.

---

I guess an update has caused a regression in some package. I am assuming there is a script somewhere that implements the default hotkey action but I have been unable to locate it. Does such a script exist? If so, where is it? (Or is the behaviour hardwired into a binary somewhere? (I notice that my "Disappear after 10 seconds" setting in `xfce4-notifyd-config` is ignored for the F1-F4 hotkeys.) In that case, which package source would I need to investigate?)

If possible, I'd prefer to help fix the relevant upstream package than apply my old workaround.